# Python: Slot Machine Code Error

Tags: python-2.7, infinite-loop, wing-ide

I'm a beginner at using python in wing ide and I'm trying to write a slot machine program. It is not running properly, and I know it has something to do with the infinite loop but I'm not sure how to fix that loop so the code runs properly. Any ideas?

```
import random

coins = 1000
wager = 2000

print "Slot Machine"
print "You have",coins, "coins."
print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin."

while wager>coins:
    print "Your Wager is greater than the number of coins you have.",
    wager = input("")

while ((coins>0) and (wager!= 0)):
    x = random.randint(0,10)
    y = random.randint(0,10)
    z = random.randint(0,10)
    print x,
    print y,
    print z

if (x==y) and (x==z):
    coins = (coins + wager)*100
    print "You won",wager*100,". You now have" , coins, "coins per spin."
    print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that many coins per spin."
elif (x==y and x==z) or (x!=y and x==z) or (x!=y and y==z):
    coins = coins + wager*10
    print "You won" ,wager*10,". You now have", coins, "coins."
    print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin."
else:
    coins = coins - wager
    print "You won" ,wager,". You now have", coins, "coins."
    print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin.",

wager = input("")

while wager>coins:
    print "Your Wager is greater than the number of coins you have.",
    wager = input("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you may have misunderstood looping. This code is probably what you want:

```
import random

coins = 1000
wager = 2000

print "Slot Machine"

while coins > 0:
   print "You have",coins, "coins."
   print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin."
   wager = input("")
   if coins == 0:
       break
   while wager>coins:
       print "Your Wager is greater than the number of coins you have.",
       wager = input("")
   x = random.randint(0,10)
   y = random.randint(0,10)
   z = random.randint(0,10)
   print x,
   print y,
   print z

   if x==y and x==z:
       coins = (coins + wager)*100
       print "You won",wager*100,". You now have" , coins, "coins per spin."
       print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that many coins per spin."
   elif x==y or x == z:
       coins = coins + wager*10
       print "You won" ,wager*10,". You now have", coins, "coins."
       print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin."
   else:
       coins = coins - wager
       print "You lost" ,wager,". You now have", coins, "coins."
       print "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin.",
```

Notice that now everything is inside one loop that checks if your coins is greater than zero? Before the loop with the random number generation could never exit and move on to the rest of the program.

Comment: One important thing! Do not use the "input" function. when you call input, it actually evaluates whatever you put in as if it were python code. Which means that if I were to type "input shutil; shutil.rmtree('/', false)" I could delete all your files. 

Instead, you could write 'wager = int(raw_input(""))', which takes input as a string then converts it to an integer.

Comment: If I were to use the adjusted code that @riri posted the output would be something like
'Slot Machine
You have 1000 coins.
Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin. 100
1 4 9
You lost 100 . You now have 900 coins.
Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin. You have 900 coins.
Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin.'
How do I get rid of the line that says "Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin. You have 900 coins." I just want one line to say 'Press 0 to exit, any other number to play that coins per spin.'

Comment: Just move the statement outside of the so that it happens before the loops is run. If you're just starting to learn programming, I recommend writing a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 10 then from 10 down to 1, by using one loop after the other. I think it'll help teach you how loops work.